# How to get component which was clicked without having onClick event or ID

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Suppose I have a website which contains many components

```
<div>
 <p> Hello </p> 
</div> 
<div className="xyz"> 
 <p className="rbc"> More Random Text </p> 
 <img className="xma" src={path/to/image} />
</p> 
<div classsName="klm"> 
 <button> Hello</button>
</div>
... 
...
...
</div>
```

As you can notice, The component doesn't have `onClick` event or `id`,

I want to know which component is clicked so that I can add a marker or annotate it. How Can/should I do it?

Comment: Why not add a listener to the element? And because of the way React works it will be hard work to add markers/annotations unless you're using state/a reference to codify markers/identify elements in the interface, and how you're going to achieve that isn't clear from your question. Just adding a listener to the document won't be enough, or is it likely to be the best process.

Answer (score 1):

Attach an event listener to the document and get the event target:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  console.log(e.target)
})
```

```html
<div>
 <p> Hello </p> 
</div> 
<div className="xyz"> 
 <p className="rbc"> More Random Text </p> 
 <img className="xma" src={path/to/image} />
</p> 
<div classsName="klm"> 
 <button> Hello</button>
</div>
```